# .me domain not playing nice with Facebook OAuth

Tags: facebook, oauth

When I call the Facebook OAuth endpoint like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.me
&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream
&state=aa48a8a575a0e308123b7f178047dd87
```

I get a Server Error even before I get the FB Dialog.

However, if I change the `redirect_uri` to `example.com`, it works fine (in that I get to FB and then get the 'incorrect redirect uri error, because I do not own example.com).

So, basically, it seems that when my redirect_uri is `.me`, I get the server error.

Is this is a known issue with OAuth / Facebook, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Yes, but it is still a ICANN approved TLD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the sake of not leaving this unasnwered*

I never could find a solution to this at that time. It was almost certainly a FB bug. More recently, I had to do this again, and found a `.me` domain to work just fine, so it seems the bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirect url from your domain on  the .com domain

For eg. `example.com/xyz` and try redirecting this url to your url on the `.me` domain on which you want the user to be redirected to.

Or try using a url shortner for shortning your redirect url like `bit.ly` or `goo.gl` (but that might not workout)

Comment: The problem is I don't own the .com domain. Just the .me

Comment: Did you add the .me domain in the App domains at  http://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: I did. And then double checked it and triple checked it.